# I want to read till the second last line of the file in JAVA

Tags: java

Every time the user logins.I'm reading till the **SECOND LAST LINE OF THE FILE** [image: The file structure looks like (for reference)].I want to know what changes i need to make to the code so that i can read only till the second last line of the file.

```
public static boolean User(String usid) {

        try {
            String acc = usid;
            File file = new File("C:\\Temp\\logs\\bank.log");
            Scanner myReader = new Scanner(file);
            while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = myReader.nextLine();
                String[] substrings = data.split("[:]");
                if (substrings[5].contains(acc) && substrings[4].contains("Login Successful for user")) {
                    a = true;
                } else {
                    a = false;
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Could anyone please guide me what changes i need to make to the above code **to read till the second last line of the file**.***[NOTE:-The contents of this file keeps adding once the user logins or logout.]***

Comment: your answer at [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20616663/3112428)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read whole the text in text file except last line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616560/how-to-read-whole-the-text-in-text-file-except-last-line)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can modify as per your requirement

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test{



    public static boolean User(String usid) {
boolean a=false;
String fileName = "c://lines.txt";
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String acc = usid;
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName))) {

            //br returns as stream and convert it into a List
            list = br.lines().collect(Collectors.toList());

            for(int i=0; i<list.size()-1; i++){
            String data = list.get(i);
                            String[] substrings = data.split("[:]");
                            if (substrings[5].contains(acc) && substrings[4].contains("Login Successful for user")) {
                                a = true;
                            } else {
                                a = false;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return a;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered at [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20616663/3112428)